# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings slf4j-test vs logback-classic

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, junit, slf4j

I know what you're all gonna say, this is a duplicate question, etc... But it is not. Because I have done the `exclusion` configurations suggested in [slf4j-test](https://projects.lidalia.org.uk/slf4j-test/) and I still get the error below whenever I run my tests:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/uk/org/lidalia/slf4j-test/1.2.0/slf4j-test-1.2.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

The dependency tree tells me that the spring-jpa includes `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` dependency.

```
% mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building weblio-help 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ weblio-help ---
[INFO] jp.weblio.help:weblio-help:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] \- uk.org.lidalia:slf4j-test:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    +- uk.org.lidalia:lidalia-lang:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:test
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:test
[INFO]    +- uk.org.lidalia:lidalia-slf4j-ext:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.845 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-04T14:07:54+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/125M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to use `slf4j-test` during testing. But it seems like even after including the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <classpathDependencyExcludes>ch.qos.logback:logback-classic</classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The error persists, seems like the `maven-surefire-plugin` classpath exclusion is not having any effect. Again, I have seen [slf4j-test documentation](https://projects.lidalia.org.uk/slf4j-test/).

Anyone can help me debug this tedious error!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude `logback-classic` dependency if its not required in your pom from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Edit:

In case you need logback-classic as well, you can mark it as optional in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I need that dependency for normal logging.